# Query Strings and Laravel (with inequalities)

Tags: laravel

I am creating an API in Laravel and using query strings to handle complex queries.

It is easy to handle queries like `url/item/?color=red&age=3...` to collect all items that are red and 3 years old.

But this is because these are discrete variables being queried for equality. Say for example I want to retrieve all users who registered after a certain date. How would I handle this?

I was thinking maybe:

```
url/item/?registered_later_than=DDMMYYYY
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I notice that this resource http://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/ suggests handling things like this, like this: `url/item/?registered>DDMMYYYY&sort=-registered` to retrieve all items registered later than DDMMYYYY and sort descending by the registered field. Is this easily parseable in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
url/item/?registered=>:DDMMYYYY
```

- The parameter name is the name of the attribute
- Right at the beginning of the parameter value is the operator
- Operator and value is separated by a `:` (it actually can be any separation character you want)

Other examples:

```
url/item/?name=like:foo
url/item/?email==:foo.bar@example.com
```

I agree `email==:foo` looks a bit weird. You could also use words or abbreviations ("eq", "gt", etc) instead of operator signs.

#### How to parse it

```
$filters = Input::all();
$query = Model::newQuery();
foreach($filters as $attribute => $filter){
    $parts = explode(':', $filter, 2);
    $operator = $parts[0];
    $value = $parts[1];
    $query->where($attribute, $operator, $value);
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea how you could do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not really a "better way" but you can try something like this :

```
url/item/?operator=lt&date=20141223
```

Operator can be :

- **lt** : lesser than
- **gt** : greater than
- **eq** : equals to
- etc.

Or whatever you want (maybe it's more readable with in full text: "greater_than", etc.). Hope I understood well your question and it will help you.